# C# way to write Func with void return

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates, refactoring, action, func

I have the following two functions, that are nearly identical, the only difference is that one uses `func`, the other `action`.  And I'd like to combine them into one function if it is possible.

```
    private static void TryCatch(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Emailer.LogError(x);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static TResult TryCatch<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Emailer.LogError(x);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining these two into one function in C# really isn't possible.  The `void` in C#, and CLR, simply isn't a type and hence has different return semantics than a non-void function.  The only way to properly implement such a pattern is to provide an overload for void and non-void delegates

The CLR limitation doesn't mean it's impossible to do in every CLR language.  It's just impossible in languages which use `void` to represent a function which returns no values.  This pattern is very doable in F# because it uses `Unit` instead of `void` for methods which fail to return a value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why it's not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could use your second, `Func<T>` version, to implement the `Action` method by just wrapping the Action in a lambda.  This eliminates some of the duplicated code.

```
private static void TryCatch(Action action)
{
    Func<object> fun => 
       {
           action();
           return null;
       };
    TryCatch(fun);
}
```

That being said, there is extra overhead involved in doing this, so personally, I'd probably leave it the way you currently have it implemented (especially given how short and simple your original version happens to be in this case).

Comment: Thanks, like suggested I'll leave it as is.  Sucks I can't actually reduce it into a single function.

Comment: @Chad No - you could make it a one-liner - I split it into two so you could see/understand what's happening, but your method's short enough I'd leave it as-is.  No way to eliminate the method overload, though.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, the method overload is what I was trying to remove.

Comment: @Chad I know ;)  Unfortunately, there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I do this as @ReedCopsey suggests.

This is the simplest syntax I have found:

```
private static void TryCatch( Action action )
{
    TryCatch( () => { action(); return 0; } );
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if you need to pass a parameter to the Func?